# Bootstrap Popover: invert title and content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I can't use Bootstrap Tooltip because of JS conflict on my site. But Popover works. So I try to do something similir to Tooltip with Popover.
I would like to use "title" tag of my HTML element to use in Popover content and define a title as default.

My actual code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger hasTooltip" title="test de popover" >Click to toggle tooltip</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    !function ($) {
        $(function(){
            // tooltip demo
            $(".hasTooltip").popover({
                content: function() {
                    return "TITLE";
                },
                title:'Info', 
                trigger: "hover",  
                placement: "bottom"
             });
         })   
    }(window.jQuery)    
</script>
```

Do you have an idea how I should proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use `'template'` you can change as your wish

For your requirement:

Change the class as `class="popover-title"`

```
$('.hasTooltip').popover({ 'template': '<div class="popover" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-title"></div></div>' });
```

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/B1xbVjBhC6)